# UIPageViewController не работает скролинг страниц

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Начал недавно изучать **swift**, работаю над приложение где с помощью `PageViewСontroller` можно перелистывать один **View Controller**. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с `UIPageViewController`, почему-то не работает скролинг страниц, также реализовал перелистывание с помощью кнопок, чтобы хоть как-то листалось, но хотелось бы чтобы нормально скролилось.

```
class PageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate{

    var pageDescriptions = ["1","2","3","4","5"]



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.dataSource = dataSource
        self.delegate = delegate

        if let startTableVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: 0) {
            setViewControllers([startTableVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }



    func nextPageWithIndex(index: Int)
    {
        if let nextTableVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: index + 1) {
            setViewControllers([nextTableVC], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    func previousPageWithIndex(index: Int)
    {
        if let previousTableVC = self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: index - 1) {
            setViewControllers([previousTableVC], direction: .reverse, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }



    func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> TableViewController?
    {
         //Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
        if index == NSNotFound || index = self.pageDescriptions.count {
            return nil
        }

        if let tableViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TableCell") as? TableViewController {
            tableViewController.date = pageDescriptions[index]
            tableViewController.index = index

            return tableViewController
        }
        return nil
    }

    //
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
        var index = (viewController as! TableViewController).index
        index -= 1
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: index)


    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController?{
        var index = (viewController as! TableViewController).index
        index += 1
        return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index: index)

    }

    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
    {
        return self.pageDescriptions.count
    }

    func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int
    {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: self.dataSource = dataSource
        self.delegate = delegate это что?

Comment: @VAndrJ спасибо вам большое, я вот сам пока не до конца понимаю что это такое, но я попытался разобраться и поменял эти строчки на эти    dataSource = self
        delegate = self.    и все заработало

Comment: Если кратко и грубо, имеется поле delegate, которое является слабой ссылкой на объект, реализующий протокол  `UIPageViewControllerDelegate`. При определенных условиях происходит действие, которое дергает метод этого объекта: `delegate.pageViewController(...)`. В Вашем случае этот объект - экземпляр класса `PageViewController`. Т.е. Вы передавали не то, дергались методы не того объекта и ничего не получалось.